# Mapping href value with page urls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few anchor tags inside a div and I need to retrieve the href values of all anchor tags.
For example

```
<div id="sample">
<ul>
<li><a href="/location1">Location1</a></li>
<li><a href="/location2">Location2</a></li>
<li><a href="/location3">Location3</a></li>
<li><a href="/location4">Location4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Assuming I am in `/location1`, the `li` that has a `href="/location1"` should have a separate background color, say for example red. If I am in `/location2` the corresponding `li` should have the same red color.

I am trying to retrieve the page url first and then store it in a variable.

```
var pageurl = (window.location.pathname);
```

But not too sure on how to retrieve the href and then map it based on the page urls.

Comment: They aren't anchors, they're URLs proper.

Comment: What have your tried? show us some code!

Comment: Which server site language are you using

Comment: I need to achieve this in simple javascript

Answer (score 2):

You do something like this:

```
// Get the active link first
var $links = $('#sample a').filter(function() {
    return this.href && this.href == location.pathname;
});

// Highlight the current li having the link
$links.closest('li').addClass('active');
```

In the active class set whatever style you want to apply.

Comment: The active class is not getting applied.

Comment: Run this.. `alert(window.location.pathname)` first what you are getting? `/location1` or `/location1/` ?

Comment: The added slash can be mitigated by using indexOf instead of ==

Comment: Yes..buy executing alert(window.location.pathname) i get /location1, location2 etc

Answer (score 0):

This is jQuery code, need to add jQuery library to work. It will work on page load

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var url=document.URL.split('?')[1];
    if(url == undefined){
        url = '';
    }
    if(url != ''){
        url = '#'+url;
        jQuery(url).trigger('click');
    }
    var url=document.URL.split('?')[1];
    if(url == undefined){
        url = '';
    }
    if(url != ''){                      
        // do here what you want to do
    }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sample ul li a').each(function(e){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        // do something with href
    });
```

});